# Android:Animated menu not dissappearing

Tags: android, popup, translation, reset

I am dealing with a view flipper. I have 2 views in my view flipper and in the second view  on completing a frame animation an animated popup menu translating from bottom. when I press the back button I could able to flip to  first view from second but again when I switch to the second view from first view that popup menu is not disappearing. I used reset() and setfillafter() methods but no result
How to solve this? any Idea?

Here is my code.

```
 final Animation popup = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 200, 0);
            popup.setDuration(20000);
            popup.setFillAfter(true);


hearttap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View view) {

final  RelativeLayout popuplayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.popuplayout);
                final ImageView ekgimgview4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ekgimgview4);
                ekgimgview4.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                ekgimgview4.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.ekgtimer);

AnimationDrawable ekgframeAnimation4 = (AnimationDrawable) ekgimgview4
                        .getBackground();

                if (ekgframeAnimation4.isRunning()) {
                    findViewById(R.id.ekgimgview4).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                    //  openOptionsMenu();
                        popuplayout.startAnimation(popup);
                        popup.setFillAfter(true);
                        popup.setStartTime(30000);
                        ekgimgview4.setVisibility(view.GONE);

                    }
                }, 30000); 


final   Button ekgbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ekgbutton);
        ekgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick( View view) {

         RelativeLayout popuplayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.popuplayout);

            popuplayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the dismiss() function for popups. So use the following code whenever you transition between Views:

```
popup.dismiss();
```

I would edit it into your code myself, but the way StackOverflow handles displaying code tags made your code half into HTML code tags and half not.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but  is dismiss() is an inbuilt method? ctrl+tab  not showing this method/functionality

Comment: @Jamesdroid: Sorry, I thought that popup was a PopupWindow. Have you tried the cancel() method?